# C Program to search a file and print certain words into a new file

Tags: c, arrays, file, search, eof

So I need to write a C program that :

1. asks user to input letter of first name
2. open a file with a list of 1200 names
3. search the file for all names that begin with the letter inputted by user
4. write all found names into a new file named based on the letter inputted (ex. aNames.txt)

Here's what I have so far. I'm okay taking the original file and putting all the names in an array but I'm stuck for how to take a user input and get it to search for that first letter of every name. Should I use a 2d array instead? Sorry I'm very new please help! Thanks

```
#define SIZE 1200

int main()
{

FILE *filePtr;
int i = 0;
char arrChar[SIZE];
char name[20];
char letter;

printf("Enter letter to search names that start with it:");
scanf("%c", letter);

filePtr = fopen("names.txt", "r");
while(fscanf(filePtr, "%s", arrChar) != EOF)
```

Comment: I may look at this more in detail later, but I would expect that if you wanted to write to a new file, you would do that on the command line by "piping" it into a new file rather than doing it in the C code. While you certainly can do it all in the C code by simply printing it. For example, once you iterate over every word from the file, if the current word starts with the user inputted character, simply printf("%s", the word) + a new line (keep in mind this is pseudo-code. Then, when you run your program, just run it as `./myprogram > aNames.txt`. Is this allowed? Or does it all need to be do

Comment: So yeah it all needs to be done by running the program. I'm only allowed to use C and not use the command line.

Comment: Why are you prompting for the character?  Take that value as a command line parameter.  (Imagine if grep behaved by prompting for a pattern to seek!)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char getNxtPntdVal(FILE *fPntr) {
    char holder;
    holder = fgetc(fPntr);
    return holder;
}


void writeToFile(char c){
    FILE *fpt = fopen("/home/jrinder/CLionProjects/untitled17/namesOut.txt","a");
    fputc(c,fpt);
    fclose(fpt);
}

int main() {

    FILE *filePtr;

    char arrChar[1200];
    char name[20];
    char letter;
    char ch;
    char ch2;
    int charNum=0;
    filePtr = fopen("/home/jrinder/CLionProjects/untitled17/names.txt","r");
    printf("Letter:");
    letter=getchar();



    while((ch=fgetc(filePtr))!=EOF){
        if(ch==letter && charNum ==0) {
            ch2 = ch;
            while (ch2 != '\n') {
                printf("%c", ch2);
                writeToFile(ch2);
                ch2 = getNxtPntdVal(filePtr);
            }
            charNum=charNum+1;
            printf("\n");
            writeToFile('\n');

        } else if(ch=='\n') {
            charNum=0;
        }else{
            charNum=charNum+1;
        }


    }
```

}

Comment: this is very helpful thank you! Ill see what i can do

Comment: Hello @JR87, wouldn't the current implementation print the names even if the  `letter` being searched for is not at the beginning of a name. For example: if the name is `Macbeth` and the letter is `c`, the output would display `cbeth`, instead of ignoring the name altogether.

Comment: As was just pointed out, when I run this as is and enter A, it prints every name that has an A in it, even if it doesnt start with A. For example it prints Casey and Asey. It also just prints those question marks forever after it prints the names.  Any ideas why? I'm trying to figure it out myself :')

Comment: Good catch, I'm doing this at work on the side on my personal laptop. Don't have a C Compiler on the work PC. Updated code

Comment: Updated again. Didn't copy paste and made a type-o. Should be good

Comment: I suggest changing the code to user existing IO functions (scanf, fgets, ...). Doing character by character IO, is usually not considered the best approach for those kind of problems. Opening the file for each character will not get you a good grade!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution, using strings IO (fscanf, fprintf), and not character by character IO (getchar/putchar):

Also arranging declaration - defer to the point when it's needed + combine with initial value, if possible ;

```
#define SIZE 1200

int main()
{
char letter;
printf("Enter letter to search names that start with it:");
scanf("%c", letter);

FILE *filePtr = fopen("names.txt", "r");
if ( !filePtr ) ... // error handling

char out_name[20] = "?Names.txt" ;
name[0] = letter ;
FILE *out = fopen(out_name, "w") ;
if ( !out ) ... // error handling

char arrChar[SIZE];
while(fscanf(filePtr, "%s", arrChar) != EOF)
   if ( arrChar[0] == letter ) fprintf(out, "%s\n", arrChar) ;
}
fclose(out) ;
fclose(filePtr) ;
```